# How do I make my local windows 7 environment use ipv4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, windows-7

I have an ASPX MVC v3 applications that is using

```
String sourceIp = Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
```

to get the IP Address. The problem is that this is returning me the IPv6 version. I need the IPv4 version.

My understanding is that there is nothing the website can do to get the IPv4 version, what I need to do is tell the server (my computer, this is local development) to use IPv4 instead of IPv6.

We have turned off IPv6 in the `Local Area Connection Status -> Properties` but its still grabbing the IPv6 version.

**How can I get the IPv4 address?**

Note: I need the IPv4 because we are using a third party service that requires the ip as  one of the parameters in IPv4 format.

**ANSWER**

*Need to wait 8 hours before I can post answer*

Worked out an easy work around. When I press debug it opens up IE with `http://localhost:8023/mysite`, if change the `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` then it will use 127.0.0.1 as the ip address, which is IPv4 format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked out an easy work around. When I press debug it opens up IE with http://localhost:8023/mysite, if change the *localhost* to *127.0.0.1* then it will use *127.0.0.1* as the ip address, which is IPv4 format.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend checking the HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR value first as discussed in Phil Haack's post ["A Gotcha Identifying the User's IP Address"](http://haacked.com/archive/2006/10/11/A_Gotcha_Identifying_the_Users_IP_Address.aspx)

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]
```

Here is a [great code sample](http://tutorialgenius.blogspot.com/2010/09/aspnet-get-ipv4-address-even-if-user-is.html) showing exactly how to do it

Comment: We have looked into that. It returned null. And from what I've read it will return an IPv6 version as well if there is one.

Comment: As a suggestion, this question may get some better answers on http://serverfault.com/